# Discrepency in unanswered questions counts

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, statistics

On [Raspberry Pi Beta](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions), I notice that if I use the lower "unanswered" tab (the one in line with "All Questions"), the count is 1,432 questions.

If I use the upper "Unanswered" tab (in line with the site title), I get 1,383 "questions with no upvoted or accepted answers".  This changes the options in the lower tab, one of which is "no answers".  Clicking here, I now get 1,083 "questions with no answers".

If I run

```
select Id from Posts where PostTypeId=1 and AnswerCount=0;
```

in the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/raspberrypi/queries), I get 1158 rows back.

Which of these is correct, and why is the first one (1,432) so much higher than the others?  I understand that the numbers may only be updated periodically, but that difference in particular seems much too great for this to be the reason.

To clarify:

- 1,432 is the number of "unanswered questions".
- 1,383 is the number of "questions with no upvoted or accepted answers".
- 1,083 is the number of "questions with no answer"
- 1,158 is the number of questions with no answer in the data explorer.  This is not live data, but that means it should be smaller, not larger, than 1,083.  I promise we did not offset this with answers to the tune of 80 questions this week.

The first three are obviously live because they fluctuate. The difference between the first two is ~50, implying they actually don't refer to the same thing, and the difference between the last two seems too great (and in the wrong direction) to be explained by the a live vs. data explorer source.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct.

The definition of "Unanswered" is questions that have no answers with a positive score (or no accepted answers).

Additionally, the data explorer is **not** live data - it is a weekly snapshot, so it is out of date.

Comment: And the Data Explorer number is out of sync since the it's only updated once a week.

Comment: "Both" meaning both of which?  There are *four* different numbers there.  And as mentioned @AnnaLear , the difference between the data explorer number is simply too great to be because of a week offset; the site has been around for two years, **this figure is not going to change by 20%+ in 7 days.**

Comment: Sorry, my bad: the dif with the data explorer answer is only 5-10%, but the data explorer one is actually *higher*, which our unanswered rate is almost certainly steadily increasing.  Then there's the 1,432 vs.1,383 number for "questions with no accepted or upvoted answer".

Comment: @Oded -- I've flagged this Q for deletion as it has been sorted out **[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244340/discrepancy-in-the-number-of-questions-with-no-accepted-or-upvoted-answers)** -- I know it's a few points to you :( but it of course requires you delete this answer first.  I think you had it w/ the reference to *positive* score but without contrast or further explanation there wasn't much chance of someone who didn't get it already (me) getting it just from that.