# Up-voted question with down-voted answers not listed as "Unanswered"

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

[This question on Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/29211/how-to-explain-a-life-as-a-researcher-to-friends-family-and-partners-who-arent) has 15 up-votes and no up-voted answers.
If one selects "Unanswered" from the top banner, it is not listed as an unanswered question.

This is the case for all questions with up-votes but down-voted answers, and seems like a very bad idea: getting a down-voted answer should not cause a question to be considered answered.

This is also contrary to the documented behavior described in prior questions:

- [Unexpected Results From Clicking The Unanswered Button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4146/unexpected-results-from-clicking-the-unanswered-button)
- [Discrepency in unanswered questions counts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244330/discrepency-in-unanswered-questions-counts)

---

In comments, it is claimed that this behavior is intended.  If this is the case, then the bug is the description of the top-level "Unanswered" page, which currently says:

> questions with no upvoted or accepted answers

but should instead say something like

> questions with no upvoted or accepted answer and no downvoted answers

Comment: Not a bug. To get questions with no upvoted answer (which is what you are looking for) go to the full questions page --> Unanswered tab. http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered

Comment: @ShadowWizard If this is the intended behavior, then the bug is the words on the right side of the top-level "Unanswered" page that say: "questions with no upvoted or accepted answers."

Comment: Hmm.... on third look I found [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28551/are-page-references-required-when-citing-the-same-quote-multiple-times) does appear there. So looks like the real check is "answers with no votes", or with 0 score - but you better edit the report here to focus on the bug with wording.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Done

Comment: Cheers, now I can upvote. :)

Comment: This question has been marked as "duplicate of an answered question", but the linked question has no answer.

Comment: This is not duplicate. Voted to reopen as well, cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Frankly, I don't agree that the bug is with the message. True the message is not accurate as it stands today, but the message is seems to be accurate for the intended purpose of that page.

My impression of the goal of that page is to show questions that do not have a good answer, so why should questions with only downvoted answers not appear? Since someone obviously felt the answer wasn't good or didn't answer the question, we should show it to people looking for unanswered questions to answer.

If the intended design of the unanswered page is to not show questions with a downvoted answer, then this should a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to change the design, rather than change the message.